# Recursive OCaml function not working

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm using the following code to try and put the average of consecutive numbers in an integer list into a new list:

```
 let newList = []
let rec average2 xs = 
match xs with
| [] -> newList
| x :: [] -> newList
| x :: x' :: [xs] -> append newList [((x + x')/2)] average2 x' :: [xs];;
```

but I keep getting the following error and don't understand why:
    Error: This function has type 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list                                                                                         It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.

Comment: Why do you have `newList`? It's always an empty list.

Comment: @Palle I want to use it as a kin of variable to keep adding elements to

Comment: `newList` is constant and it's never read from in the code.

Comment: Am I not appending thing to the list in the third line of pattern matching

Comment: The `append` function returns a new list where the first list is appended to the second list. No arguments will get mutated.

Comment: Also your pattern matching is not exhaustive. In the last case you just match a list with a single element with `[xs]`. To match an arbitrary amount of elements, use `x :: x' :: xs` instead, where xs is a list containing zero or more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `average2` function to the `append` function instead of calling it in the last line. Also, `newList` is empty and does not get mutated nor read from. You can just add a new head to the list when returning it.

Change it to

```
((x + x')/2) :: (average2 x' :: [xs])
```

Comment: Remove `newList` from the argument list. It's an empty list anyway.